# How to traverse through Source code only using debugger - Rails 3.2.13

Tags: debugging, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rubygems

In my Rails app, using `Ruby 2.0.0-p0` and `Rails 3.2.13`, I also use the gem `debugger` for debugging purpose. If I have to debug an area in my source code, for e.g. a controller method, I will put `debugger` inbetween and when I execute the action, it will go to the source code and then travserse through the framework code a lot and that really mess-up the normal debugging. I can see many commands through help, but don't know how to handle with that.

I just want to traverse through the source code only..

Please help me to have a solution. Thanks :)-

Answer (score 1):

Use [byebug](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug) instead. It was created to overcome `debugger`'s problems with ruby-2.0.0, like the one that makes it "step" when you use command "next", unexpectedly leading you to framework sources.

*Disclaimer: I'm `byebug`'s author*

Comment: Thanks for giving me another option. Anyway I just want to know how we can do it with debugger and I hope debugger is a widely used gem

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't properly explain myself. _Debugger just doesn't work for Ruby 2.0_. If you still want to use it, either wait for a patch to be released or put up with the current behaviour... Good luck!